# How to modify an annotation attribute before Java compile time?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have the following structure in my class

```
public class ExampleResponseGenerator extends CustomAbstractClass {
    @Override
    @ConfigurableAnnotation(
            name = "Example_Configurable_ResponseGenerator",
            schema = "{\"properties\":{\"singleField\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"default\":\"DefaultValue\"}}}"
    )
    // method implementation
}
```

I'm writing a "script" using Java which would before compile time modify the content of the schema annotation

I'm wondering what would be the optimal option:

- using Regex, it might get buggy
- using javaparser-core lib:

  ```xml
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.javaparser</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaparser-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.23.1</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- processing API is not an option since it will create a new class but I just need to modify the schema from an existing class
  Is there another approach which would be more suitable?

Comment: Are you aware of the annotation processing API?

Comment: Looking at it right now. I guess it filters out the annotated class and then I can do manipulation on it? It also creates a new class, but I don't need that.

Comment: If you can live with less portability, i.e. working with `javac` but not `ecj`, you can use the [extended compiler API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/jdk.compiler/module-summary.html) from within your annotation processor to modify the AST. Otherwise, I’d write a tool patching the class files after compilation. There are libraries like ASM for processing class files and it’s more reliable than applying regex on source code. After all, the class file format is designed to be processed by machines.